# Wrong user interface in Reactjs Video Player

Tags: reactjs, media-player

I am designing media player in reactjs web but the actual look that the media player used to have, I am not getting that look. What changes should I make in the below code?

```js
<Player ref="player"
poster='https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png'
src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"   
            fluid="false"
            width="2px"
            height="2px"
            preload="auto"
            aspectRatio="9:9"
        >
        <ControlBar  autoHide={false}>
        <ForwardControl seconds={5} order={3.1}/>
        </ControlBar>
        </Player>
```

There are no icons here in the player

[image: X]

Comment: it seems you have on '>' useless at the end of your code

Comment: '>' sign is not useless, its the closing tag for <Player>

Answer (score 0):

I myself have corrected this issue.
There is a need to import css file found at '../node-modules/video-react/dist/video-react.css' in main react file.